# gzip compression with gzhandler php for 4kb file

Tags: php, json, compression, gzip

I wanted to implement a gzip compression functionality for json output that
my php script does, for a quicker way I decided to gzip the json content
via this function `ob_start("ob_gzhandler");`

The Original file json content output is around 4kb uncompressed, and it 
becomes 0.7kb after compression.

Does it make any sense to compress at such small file size or I should not
compress at all, as it won't make any significant difference on the speed
of download and it might be a bad idea to put more strain on my vps cpu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Apache and have `mod_deflate` you can add the following to your `.htaccess`.

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/json application/json
```

For NGINX you can add the following to your `site.conf` file.

```
gzip on;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
gzip_vary on;
gzip_types text/json application/json;
```

Comment: Does it work with php files that output json?

Also do you think is worth to compress and save 3kb on each request when the total size of the request is 4kb uncompressed? Or I should not bother
Thanks.

Comment: @Ryan you will need to test it in your browser to make sure its coming through compressed, if it is not you can always try adding `application/x-httpd-php`.